# binding image with Datagrid in asp.net not working well

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I'm displaying information in a Datagrid not gridView in asp.net. the datagrid contain a column called Status. the status can either be 1 or -1. if the status is 1, i'm displaying a mark icon, then if the status is -1 then displayed a cancel icon. i have done the coding and its working but the problem is, the icons are not showing in all the column depending on the condition as shown in the image below. based on the value in my databasee, the status columns are all -1 but if its showing, its skip on column and bind the next column and so on.[image]

here is my DataGrid Markup

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="VehicleInfo" runat ="server"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="939px" CssClass=" table table-striped table-bordered" AllowCustomPaging="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" OnItemDataBound="VehicleInfo_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="VehicleInfo_ItemCommand" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="#" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataSetIndex + 1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>           
       </asp:TemplateColumn>      

      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Type" HeaderText="Veh. Type"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Make" HeaderText="Make/Model"></asp:BoundColumn>
       <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Veh. Reg No">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="RegNo" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,   "DataItem.RegistrationNo") %>'></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EngineNumber" HeaderText="Engine No"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ChasisNo" HeaderText="Chasis No"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="InjectionYear" HeaderText="Injection Year"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Size" HeaderText="Veh. Size"></asp:BoundColumn>
      <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ServiceTypeName" HeaderText="Service Type"></asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Response Status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Status" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#   DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.registrationstatusResponse") %>'></asp:Label>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="cancel" Width="30" Height="30" ImageUrl="/images/cancel.png" Runat=server Visible="false" />
             <asp:ImageButton ID="good" Width="30" Height="30" ImageUrl="/images/good.png" Runat=server Visible="false" />

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="verificationComment" HeaderText="Remark"></asp:BoundColumn>       

   </Columns>
 <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" CssClass=""   ForeColor="White" BackColor="#428BCA" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
   <ItemStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" />


   </asp:DataGrid>
```

and here is my code on the itemDataBound event and i Even try using a loop on the ItemDataBound event but it doesn't work. Please i need your help if there is anything im missing.

```
protected void VehicleInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item))
    {
        var lab1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("status");
        var img1 = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("good");
        var img2 = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("cancel");

        if (lab1.Text == "1")
        {
            img2.Visible = false;
            img1.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (lab1.Text == "-1")
        {
            img2.Visible = true;
            img1.Visible = false;

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: lab1.Text is indeed `1`? Or for that matter the `DataItem.registrationstatusResponse`? As in not `+1` or `[space]1`

Comment: lab1.Text can either be 1 or -1. there is no space. i do cross check.

Comment: did you debug it? If no image is shown then there are row which value is neither "1" or "-1".

Comment: I do debug. in fact i set all the row to be -1 and if its 1 then and image is meant to show.

Comment: are you really sure the good.png image exists? that might be your issue...

Comment: the good.png image exist. my problem now is that, the cancel.png is suppose to show in all the rows coz what i have in my table for the  registrationstatusResponse is -1 but its skipping one row.